# new networkStream quais argumentos usar?

Tags: c#, tcp

é o seguinte eu tenho um server tcp e um client, o client tem tem numa parte do código o seguinte

```
        private void SendDesktop()
    {   
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        ns = new NetworkStream();
        ns = client.GetStream();
        bf.Serialize(ns, Desktop());
    }
```

nesta parte `ns = new NetworkStream();` tem um erro que não tem argumentos eu gostaria de por um argumento mas não sei qual. alguem pode me dizer o que é suposto eu por como argumento?

Se percisarem do código enteiro tem aqui

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace DesktopClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = null;
        int port = 0;

        public Image  Desktop()
        {
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
            Bitmap Screenshot = null;
            Graphics graph = null;
            bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            Screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            graph = Graphics.FromImage(Screenshot);
            graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            return Screenshot;               
        }

        private void SendDesktop()
        {   
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            ns = new NetworkStream();
            ns = client.GetStream();
            bf.Serialize(ns, Desktop());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ConnectBtb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port = int.Parse(PortBox.Text);
            try
            {
                client.Connect(Ipbox.Text, port);
                label3.Text = "Connected";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                label3.Text = "Faild To Connect";
            }
        }

        private void ShareBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start(); 
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendDesktop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A gente também não sabe, afinal o código é seu, mas sempre que tiver dúvidas de como usar um método é só consultar a documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Veja essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989178/read-a-network-stream-from-a-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O construtor **NetworkStream()** requisita um parâmetro do tipo **Socket**, ou seja, ele precisa saber o socket correspondente para enviar e receber **bytes**. Pelo que notei, sua aplicação é do tipo *client* você deve criar um socket para estabelecer ligações entre dois computadores:

```
string strEnderecoIP = "192.168.1.14";
                IPEndPoint pointCliente = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(strEnderecoIP), 5486);
                Socket clienteSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
```

A variável *strEnderecoIP* guarda o IP de conexão com o servidor seguido da porta especificada no **endpoint**. Após isso basta obter a matriz de bytes correspondente ao arquivo:

```
clienteSocket.Connect(pointCliente);
clienteSocket.Send(byteArr, 0, byteArr.Length, 0);
                clienteSocket.Close();
```

Onde *byteArr* é a matriz de bytes do arquivo a ser enviado.

Obs: Lembre-se de especificar uma porta reservada por padrão aos serviços de rede do computador.

Você pode também encontrar mais informações na documentação da Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Como é que eu defino byteArr?

Comment: Eu fiz esta variavel `private byte[] byteArr;` mas o programa disse `A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.`se me podeses ajudar quanto a isto agradecia enquanto isso vou continuar a procurar como se faz.